# Hyperplane problem by Lagrange multiplier method

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, lagrange-multiplier, maximum-principle

Solve the problem using Lagrange multiplier method.

Find the point that belongs to both hyperplanes xT c = β and xT d = γ which is
closest to the origin.

Comment: What did you try ?

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**: What does each partial derivative of these products and of $\|\mathbf x\|^2$ look like?